# How to get data from getter setter class?

Tags: java, android, api

I am beginner in android development , I have some issue please help me.
I have 2 screen Login and After Login , I have set User id in login class and i want to use that user_id in after login how to get , when I use get method find Null how to resolve this problem.
here is my Login Code`public class LoginActivity extends FragmentActivity {

```
private EditText userName;
private EditText password;
private TextView forgotPassword;
private TextView backToHome;
private Button login;
private CallbackManager callbackManager;
private ReferanceWapper referanceWapper;
private LoginBean loginBean;
Context context;
String regid;
GoogleCloudMessaging gcm;
String SENDER_ID = "918285686540";

public static final String PROPERTY_REG_ID = "registration_id";
private static final String PROPERTY_APP_VERSION = "appVersion";
private final static int PLAY_SERVICES_RESOLUTION_REQUEST = 9000;
static final String TAG = "GCM";


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);
    Utility.setStatusBarColor(this, R.color.tranparentColor);
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    Typeface tf = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "fonts/OpenSans_Regular.ttf");
    setupUI(findViewById(R.id.parentEdit));

    userName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.userName);
    userName.setTypeface(tf);
    userName.setFocusable(false);
    userName.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent paramMotionEvent) {
            userName.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
            Utility.hideSoftKeyboard(LoginActivity.this);
            return false;
        }
    });


    password = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.passwordEText);
    password.setTypeface(tf);
    password.setFocusable(false);
    password.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        public boolean onTouch(View paramView, MotionEvent paramMotionEvent) {
            password.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
            Utility.hideSoftKeyboard(LoginActivity.this);
            return false;
        }
    });


    forgotPassword = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.forgotPassword);
    forgotPassword.setTypeface(tf);
    forgotPassword.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),ForgotPasswordActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });

    backToHome = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.fromLogToHome);
    backToHome.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            onBackPressed();
        }
    });
    login = (Button) findViewById(R.id.loginBtn);

    login.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            doLoginTask();
            //  Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), AfterLoginActivity.class);
            //  startActivity(intent);

        }
    });
}


private void doLoginTask() {

    String strEmail = userName.getText().toString();
    String strPassword = password.getText().toString();
    if (strEmail.length() == 0) {
        userName.setError("Email Not Valid");
    } else if (!Utility.isEmailValid(strEmail.trim())) {
        userName.setError("Email Not Valid");
    } else if (strPassword.length() == 0) {
        password.setError(getString(R.string.password_empty));
    } else {

        JSONObject jsonObject = null;
        try {
            jsonObject = new JSONObject();
            jsonObject.putOpt(Constants.USER_NAME, strEmail);
            jsonObject.putOpt(Constants.USER_PASSWORD, strPassword);
            jsonObject.putOpt(Constants.DEVICE_TOKEN, "11");
            jsonObject.putOpt(Constants.MAC_ADDRESS, "111");
            jsonObject.putOpt(Constants.GPS_LATITUDE, "1111");
            jsonObject.putOpt(Constants.GPS_LONGITUDE, "11111");
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        final ProgressDialog pDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
        pDialog.setMessage("Loading...");
        pDialog.show();

        CustomJSONObjectRequest jsonObjectRequest = new CustomJSONObjectRequest(Request.Method.POST, Constants.USER_LOGIN_URL, jsonObject, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                pDialog.dismiss();
                Log.e("LoginPage", "OnResponse =" + response.toString());
                getLogin(response);
                //LoginBean lb = new LoginBean();
                //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),lb.getFull_name()+"Login Successfuly",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),AfterLoginActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Something, wrong please try again",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                pDialog.dismiss();

            }
        });
        jsonObjectRequest.setRetryPolicy(new DefaultRetryPolicy(
                5000,
                DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_MAX_RETRIES,
                DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_BACKOFF_MULT));
        Log.e("LoginPage", "Url= " + Constants.USER_LOGIN_URL + " PostObject = " + jsonObject.toString());
        AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(jsonObjectRequest);
    }

}

public void getLogin(JSONObject response) {
    LoginBean loginBean = new LoginBean();
    if (response != null){
        try {
            JSONObject jsonObject = response.getJSONObject("data");
            loginBean.setUser_id(jsonObject.getString("user_id"));
            loginBean.setFull_name(jsonObject.getString("full_name"));
            loginBean.setDisplay_name(jsonObject.getString("display_name"));
            loginBean.setUser_image(jsonObject.getString("user_image"));
            loginBean.setGender(jsonObject.getString("gender"));
            loginBean.setAuthorization_key(jsonObject.getString("authorization_key"));

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"User id is "+loginBean.getUser_id(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
public void onBackPressed() {
    finish();
}

public void setupUI(View view) {

    //Set up touch listener for non-text box views to hide keyboard.
    if (!(view instanceof EditText)) {

        view.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {

            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                Utility.hideSoftKeyboard(LoginActivity.this);
                return false;
            }

        });
    }


}
```

}
`

here is my AfterLogin class`public class AfterLoginActivity extends FragmentActivity {

```
private ImageView partyIcon;
private ImageView dealIcon;
private ImageView deliveryIcon;
private TextView  txtParty;
private TextView  txtDeals;
private TextView  txtDelivery;
boolean doubleBackToExitPressedOnce = false;
int backButtonCount = 0;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_after_login);
    Utility.setStatusBarColor(this, R.color.splash_status_color);
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

    partyIcon = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.party_Icon);
    dealIcon = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.deals_Icon);
    deliveryIcon = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.delivery_Icon);

    partyIcon.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(getApplication(), BookPartyActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);

        }
    });
    dealIcon.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(getApplication(), DealsActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);

        }
    });
    deliveryIcon.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            LoginBean loginBean = new LoginBean();
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),"Auth"+loginBean.getUser_id(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),MyAuction.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });

}
/*
public void onBackPressed()
{


    if (doubleBackToExitPressedOnce)
    {
        Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);
        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        startActivity(intent);
        finish();
    }
    doubleBackToExitPressedOnce = true;
    Toast.makeText(this, "you have logged in ,plz enjoy the party", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable()
    {
        public void run()
        {
           doubleBackToExitPressedOnce = false;
        }
    }
            , 2000L);
}*/
@Override
public void onBackPressed()
{

    if(backButtonCount >= 1)
    {
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
        intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
    else
    {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Press the back button once again to close the application.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        backButtonCount++;
    }
}
```

}`

here is LoginBean`public class LoginBean {
    private String user_id;
    private String full_name;
    private String display_name;
    private String user_image;
    private String gender;
    private String authorization_key;

```
public void setUser_id(String user_id) {
    this.user_id = user_id;
}
public String getUser_id() {
    return user_id;
}


public void setFull_name(String full_name) {
    this.full_name = full_name;
}
public String getFull_name() {
    return full_name;
}


public void setDisplay_name(String display_name) {
    this.display_name = display_name;
}
public String getDisplay_name() {
    return display_name;
}


public void setUser_image(String user_image) {
    this.user_image = user_image;
}
public String getUser_image() {
    return user_image;
}


public void setGender(String gender) {
    this.gender = gender;
}
public String getGender() {
    return gender;
}


public void setAuthorization_key(String authorization_key) {
    this.authorization_key = authorization_key;
}
public String getAuthorization_key() {
    return authorization_key;
}
```

}`

Comment: after successful login put userId in shared preferences so you can use any time any where.It is very easy method to save and get in complete application.

Comment: This is so simple Java question. Refer to http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_encapsulation.htm to get more clear understanding.

Comment: @SuhasB after login succesful ,i want to click on deliveryBTN and message  toast As user_id

Comment: yes man you can do it.using the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
//in your both activity or create class 

    private SharedPreferences mSharedPreferences;


//in your login on getLogin() method ;

    mSharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("user_preference",Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        //save actual drawable id in this way.

       if(mSharedPreferences==null)
            return;

        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = mSharedPreferences.edit();
        editor.putInt("userId", loginBean.getUser_id());
        editor.commit();


// in your after login acvtivity on deliverable method

    private SharedPreferences mSharedPreferences;

mSharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("user_preference",Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
if(mSharedPreferences==null)
            return;
string userId = mSharedPreferences.getString("userId", "");
```

Comment: This is very helpful for me ,Thank you so much Suhas .

Answer (score 0):

You can write and apply below mentioned steps (Please ignore any syntactical error, I am giving you simple logical steps).

step 1 - Make a global application level loginObject setter and getter like below. Make sure to define Application  class in your manifest just like you do it for your LoginActivity

public class ApplicationClass extends Application{

```
private LoginBean loginObject;



public void setLoginBean(LoginBean object) {

    this.loginObject = object;
}

public LoginBean getName() {

   return this.loginObject

}
```

}

Step - 2 Get an instance of ApplicationClass object reference in LoginActivity to set this global loginObject

e.g. setLogin object in your current Loginactivity like this

......

private ApplicationClass appObject;

......

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

```
......

appObject = (ApplicationClass) LoginActivity.this.getApplication();

.......

appObject.setLoginBean(loginObject)
```

}

Step - 3 Get an instance of ApplicationClass object reference in any other Activity get this global loginObject where you need to access this login data.

e.g. getLogin object in your otherActivity like this

......

private ApplicationClass appObject;

......

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

```
......

appObject = (ApplicationClass) LoginActivity.this.getApplication();

.......

LoginBean loginObject = appObject.getLoginBean();
```

}